# How to show app offline message in Azure App Gateway when makes changes to site

Tags: .net, azure, azure-application-gateway

I am having 10+ sites configured using IIS on Windows VM & File share for the source code , Whenever there is an update to the site , if end user hits the URL it says 502 Bad gateway. what I used to do on Conventional On-prem Servers is to use app_offline.htm , so that it gives "App Offline Message "to end users.
Right now, I have added app_offline.htm to the Application Gateway Listeners and still its says 502 Bad gateway or shows few Configuration (web.config) errors while making updates

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below steps to create an alert when **Log Analytics** service stopped on VM.

I have created a **VM** and installed **Log Analytics** agent on same VM.

[image]

Once complete the VM provisioning, create Log Analytics Workspace, like below.

**Azure Portal > Log Analytics workspaces > Create >**

[image]

Enable the inventory by navigating below options.

**Azure Portal > Virtual Machine > Select your VM > Inventory**

> Note: A full collection of data can take 24 hours once complete the automation account deployment Refer [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/change-tracking/manage-inventory-vms) more about Azure VM Inventory.

[image]

When Azure VM is fully configured, the **Inventory** will show a tab with all Windows Services and their current state display, like below.

[image]

You can change the collection frequency, like below.

**Open your VM > Inventory > Edit Settings > Windows Servies**

[image]

Now you can setup an alert in **Log Analytics** to monitor the **HealthService** service.

**Query** to check the **Service**:

```
ConfigurationData
| where ConfigDataType == "WindowsServices" and SvcDisplayName == "HealthService" and SvcState == "Stopped"
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

[image]

Create an alert when OMS Agent service stopped, like below.

[image]

Create an **Alert** like below.

[image]

Create an **Action Group** for sending alerts to mail id.

[image]

Once **OMS Agent Service Stopped**, you will receive the email to registred email, like below.

[image]

Reference taken from   [create a alert when **Log Analytics** service stopped on VM](https://www.smcculloch.com/monitor-windows-service-azure-vm)

Install the Log Analytics agent on Linux computers [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/agent-linux?tabs=wrapper-script)

Install **OMS Agent** on **AKS Cluster**,    follow the [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75391858/azure-aks-oms-agent-and-diagnostic-settings-possible-together/75395057#75395057).